# Web UI: Dynamic Web Forms

Tags: php, javascript, html

consider the following data structure:

```
subject (stdClass)
    topic (stdClass)
        units (int)
        title (varchar 50)
        description (varchar 255)
        start_time (time)
        end_time (time)
    teacher (stdClass)
        first_name (varchar 50)
        last_name (varchar 50)
    students (stdClass[])
        1 (stdClass)
            first_name (varchar 50)
            last_name (varchar 50)
        2 (stdClass)
            first_name (varchar 50)
            last_name (varchar 50)
        3 (stdClass)
            first_name (varchar 50)
            last_name (varchar 50)
    proctor (stdClass)
        first_name (varchar 50)
        last_name (varchar 50)
```

I'm having a problem on how to implement the above-mentioned data-structure into dynamic web forms. I'm not sure which type of implementation I will use to make it easier for the end-user to fill-up. At the same time preserving data integrity.

Scenario:

- A user should be able to provide the
  data needed to populate the "subject"
  object in one form. Meaning he will
  not be redirected to other pages
  (like a wizard) instead, the
  sub-forms per student are javascript
  generated.
- A user should be able to alter the
  data in the "subject" object on
  demand.
- There can be many students or none.
- Validation per sub-object is
  required.

So how should I present this using web-forms?

Comment: This question is probably too broad. Its actually interesting to me, but it would be impossible to provide one answer that covered all of what you are asking.

Comment: I tried several things in this situation. Popup windows, javascript popup boxes, adding inner-html sub-form etc. I come to the conclusion that non of them are easy. For example the codes are redundant and because of that it requires an amount of work if you have to fix some fields.

Comment: +1 for an interesting question

Comment: yeah would be impossible to cover all that you want in here -- I suggest you start learning some AJAX and jQuery ;) after that, you can multiply forms by using JS to keep the user from going to a new page -- and letting them do everything inline -- you can use PHP/ASP.NET/any other server-side language to handle data integrity and database management later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm facing a similar problem with one of my projects too, how to fill a vast amount of information in a non-obtrusive manner, preserving state on edits.

Technologies already exist to do this quite nicely, namely ajax and json. My project is built with PHP so my idea is to create a view which displays all data entry forms but it saves the data incrementally by sending the completed fields to a PHP script with ajax, which then saves/updates the object.

Theoretically with some javascript niceness it should be possible to make a very efficient interface (think completed sections have a save button and slide closed, which then can be opened for further editing)

Its possible to make this a very modular design, implementing for example write once fields, once saved cant be edited.

This is indeed a very interesting topic that many sites seem to struggle with. Please tell me if I grabbed the wrong end of the stick here and posted an answer which is not relevant/helpful

To reduce duplicate code and really make this sleek and manageable I would implement it with a MVC design pattern. Have your view send data whenever user stops typing in a field and its not empty. Then have the controller check if the field needs updating and send the correct acknowledgements back down to the view. Model will play its part too as you will be no doubt saving the data into your database.

The View will essentially be a modular ajax script, it has inputs and monitors them for changes, as soon as enough changes are made (to warrant a partial save) the ajax sends the data to the controller and collapses the relevant section to show that it has been completed. Likewise if you revisit the page and the controller sees that there is some data in the model for theese fields it sends it to the ajax view, which then fills in and collapses the prefilled sections =) Quite neat i think.

Edit: fixing typos, added MVC comment

Comment: exactly! there are several implementations, but which one is the best?

Comment: To be honest with my skill-set consisting of unix, ajax and php, this is pretty much the only option left for me. There could be some way to do it with the dark side of web development, asp and IIS, but from experience i wouldn't recommend. I can expand my answer if you would like some specific implementation and/or examples.

Comment: firstly, i want to eliminate the duplicate codes. to do that, i could just code 1 html file that contains the form and pass variables to it so that the form gets populated automatically via GET var. that way we can do ajax "GET" calls at the same time pass values to it. if no values are passed then a new form is called otherwise "edit mode" is on. something like that.

Comment: I think it would be much easier if you use the MVC design pattern rather than just having the view and logic in the same place. Your controller should handle all the logic of saving, when ... this is going to be a big post, ill update my answer instead

Answer (score 1):

based on the usability guidelines, fields should be grouped in `fieldset` element based on their subject / e.g. first/lastname together etc.

due to the large amount of data, some Javascript interface should be used to show page in steps (forms could be loaded at one page, but JS would serve to display and hide respective sections/fieldsets). submit would then send all data at once or alternatively AJAX could be sued after each section updated...

best things about fieldsets is they can be grouped as well and included into one another.

Comment: javascript is my best bet at the moment to hide forms and show on-demand. there are 2 approaches either pre-load the forms on page or load the forms via ajax... I'm sure that ajax is a better choice as it doesn't slow the page load the first time. Then again how do we pass the data to the ajax form in case that we are editing the sub-record?

Comment: via AJAX again - pull them from MySQL on demand and populate required forms.